# Running an Excel Macro Overnight When Logged Off and Shut Down using Task Manager

Tags: vbscript, outlook, scheduled-tasks

I have recently put together a report for my business and I want to have it scheduled to run at 10pm to email end of play sales. 
My macro and everything runs fine.. it copies a table as text from an excel file linked to the source data via Power Query, then the table is pasted into an Outlook Email and sent to the distribution list.
Is there a way to send this out without being logged in or have my PC switched on?

I have tried using the "Run whether user is logged in or not" and "Run with highest privileges", but it wont run the task when that is selected.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here is my .bat code
`cscript "Q:\Sales\SendEmail.vbs" "Q:\Sales\Sales.xlsm"`

Here is my .vbs code

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Workbooks.Open args(0)
objExcel.Visible = True

objExcel.Run "send_email"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close(0)
objExcel.Quit
```

Is there something I'm fundamentally missing?

Comment: You can't do anything when your computer is powered off. No jobs or software can be executed without the computer powered on and the OS running, and VBScript requires Windows in order to run, so it clearly can't do so when Windows isn't running. As far as your tasks, they have to run under your own credentials (account), as that's what Excel and Outlook are installed under.

Comment: shutdown excel or shutdown computer? :v, i think you can using ggsheet for this

Comment: @TheGridLock: The poster said *without being logged on or have my PC switched on*. You can't use ggsheet to run a VBScript file on a powered off machine, either. :-)

Comment: @Ken:I mean use gg app script and use events on it, but maybe I'm misleading :)). thanks

Comment: The files are stored on a company network, would that make any difference?

Comment: If your company uses a logoff script that disconnects your mapped drives when you logoff, then yes.  Can you copy the script and Excel workbook locally to drive C:?  Also, it might be preferred to fully-qualify the location of cscript as either C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe -- if you want to run in 32-bit context; or C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe -- if you want to run in 64-bit context.

Comment: How would i do that @leeharvey1?

Comment: Copy `"Q:\Sales\SendEmail.vbs"` to `"C:\Sales\SendEmail.vbs"`.  Copy `"Q:\Sales\Sales.xlsm"` to `"C:\Sales\Sales.xlsm"`.  Ensure your `.bat` is on drive `C:`.  Update your .bat code to `C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe "C:\Sales\SendEmail.vbs" "C:\Sales\Sales.xlsm"`